# Adding a Hyperlink to Text Within a Cell with ClosedXML

Tags: closedxml

I'm using ClosedXML and C# to build an Excel output from a database query. Some of the cells contain hyperlinks within the text of the cell. IE, the cell (database output) may contain the following text:

```
"I like to watch <a href=\"https://www.cnn.com\">CNN</a> for my news"
```

Is there a way to target the specific text and convert it to a hyperlink using ClosedXML so it appears in the Excel cell as follows:

I Like to watch [CNN](https://www.cnn.com) for my news.
I've seen the following URL, but it targets the entire cell, and not just a substring within a cell?
[Using Hyperlinks - ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Using-Hyperlinks)